# how can i find address from selected country using google api

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

currently i am using google place api for address 
and i am getting it perfectly

but now i want to restict it to perticular city

here is my code

```
// Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
// location types.
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    {types: ['geocode']});

// When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
// fields in the form.
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);



 // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }
```

[image: output]
now all i want that if i select  "INDIA" from select box only indian address should appear on my text box

can any one has idea about how to restrict this

Comment: if my answer solves your problem please consider accepting it, I'm trying to be active on this platform. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add restrictions on Autocomplete while creating its object.

```
var options = {
  types: ['geocode'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "IN"}
 };

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    options);

// When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
// fields in the form.
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);



 // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }
```

As the value of country changes, change the value of

```
options.componentRestrictions.country
```

Comment: var selectedCountry
      $("#country").change(function () {
           selectedCountry = $("#country option:selected").val();
           console.log(selectedCountry);
      });  options.componentRestrictions.country = selectedCountry; this is not working for me when i change the country

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentRestrictions`

```
{types: ['geocode'],componentRestrictions: {country: 'IN'}}
```